# Dynamic Pivot in MySQL - How to loop into fields from select inside mySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Maybe an amateur question, but right now I'm not coming up with the solution and maybe someone has an idea where my thoughts are wrong.

My plan is, call a mySQL stored procedure. This procedure should return my something like that:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Date          | 100           | 101           | 102           | 103           |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2019-10-21    | 1             | 2             | 3             | 4             |
| 2019-10-20    | 0             | 2             | 3             | 4             |
| 2019-10-19    | 0             | 2             | 3             | 4             |
| 2019-10-18    | 1             | 2             | 3             | 4             |
| 2019-...      | ..            | ..            | ..            | ..            |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

The "main data" was stored in a table "loggings" which has the columns id, code, created_at. A second table "codes" contains a list of all available codes with columns id (<- code in loggings) and description.

Now, my first step was, build a stored procedure handles all dates between min and max date. Looks like this:

```
BEGIN
set @dateStart := (SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM loggings);
set @dateEnd := (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM loggings);
set @d := 0;
SELECT DATE(ADDDATE(@dateStart, INTERVAL @d:=@d+1 DAY)) AS date,
IFNULL((
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM loggings AS m2
    WHERE DATE(m2.created_at) = DATE(ADDDATE(@dateStart, INTERVAL @d DAY))
),0) AS total
FROM loggings AS m1
HAVING @d < DATEDIFF(@dateEnd, @dateStart);
END
```

Is working fine, I get a result list with all days and total sum of records per day:

```
+---------------+---------------+
| date          | total         |
+---------------+---------------+
| 2019-10-21    | 1             |
| 2019-10-20    | 2             |
| 2019-10-19    | 3             |
| 2019-10-18    | 4             |
| 2019-...      | ..            |
+---------------+---------------+
```

Now, next, the part I doesn't really recognize currently how I can solve it: How I can loop the available ids of "codes" into a set of columns for the result?
Somehow I must build a loop inside/outside the select returning dynamic fields but how?

Edit:
Sample data of logging could be:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------------------+
| id       | email    | code     | created_at           |
+----------+----------+----------+----------------------+
| 1        | a@y.de   | 100      | 2019-10-21 10:00:01  |
| 2        | b@y.de   | 100      | 2019-10-21 10:00:02  |
| 3        | c@y.de   | 101      | 2019-10-21 10:01:03  |
| 4        | d@y.de   | 102      | 2019-10-21 11:01:03  |
| 5        | a@y.de   | 100      | 2019-10-21 12:01:03  |
| 6        | b@y.de   | 103      | 2019-10-21 15:01:03  |
| 7        | e@y.de   | 106      | 2019-10-21 15:01:04  |
| 8        | f@y.de   | 108      | 2019-10-21 16:01:03  |
| 9        | g@y.de   | 109      | 2019-10-21 17:01:03  |
+----------+----------+----------+----------------------+
```

The table logs different events by their code with timestamp for creation and email as key for identify the user, triggers the "event".

Comment: Just show us your sample data from loggings table and post your expected result from that table.

Comment: I've added informatiosn about the logging table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final result you are trying to achieve is called [Dynamic pivot](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html). You may try below query to achieve your desired result -

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(case when code = ',
      code,
      ' then created_at else null end) AS ''',
      code, ''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM LOGGINGS;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT date(created_at), ', @sql, '
                   FROM LOGGINGS 
                   GROUP BY date(created_at)');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1bb190ba909bc2c4208e05ee2d54ac2f) is the fiddle.

Comment: Thank you Ankit! Exactly what I am looking for, i've learned something new again! :-)

Comment: Glad to know that I was able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

For using a loop inside the stored procedure, you can use "cursor".

Declare a cursor that contains list data you want

```
-- declare cursor
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT id FROM table;

-- declare NOT FOUND handler
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
    FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
```

Usage:

```
OPEN myCursor;

getID: LOOP
    FETCH myCursor INTO myId;

    IF finished = 1 THEN 
        LEAVE getID;
    END IF;
    -- do something you want here
    .....

END LOOP getID;
CLOSE myCursor;
```

Reference here for more info: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/

Comment: Sorry, but currently I have no idea how I can use the cursor for my situation. Do you have maybe a comparable example based on my situation? Would be nice!